# Connect two close parallel train tracks in factorio?

Tags: factorio

I have two parallel tracks in Factorio.  I'd like to connect them so a train can move from one to the other.  The planner just does not seem to allow it, no matter how I move around.  Sure, it's too close, but can I turn the train further, then closer?

[image: train tracks]

Comment: If you'd rather stick with the track separation you have instead of using the minimum-distance crossover shown in the answer, consider making a station (really two stations, I guess) where items are transferred from a train on the lower track to a train on the upper track.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To be able to make a crossover *without* going apart and together again, space your parallel tracks by 6 tiles (3 track widths; gap between them of of 4 tiles/2 tracks). Your tracks are too close by 2 tiles / 1 track width, as Factorio only has one size of curved track section, which goes too far for this situation.

Whether or not you change the layout, to get the rail planner to make a connection to the existing track, press the rotate key <kbd>R</kbd> one or more times while using the planner; this will allow you to choose the direction the track ends in to align with the existing track rather than it picking whichever is simplest to plan. Each press will rotate the track end by 45 degrees.

---

This is the smallest possible connection between parallel tracks spaced at 4 tiles:

[image: Out and back]

This is the compact crossover that is possible spaced at 6 tiles:

[image: Only 2 curves]

Answer (score 1):

In the next version of Factorio, 2.0, tracks will be able to connect without the two-track skip.

[Friday Facts #377 - New new rails](https://factorio.com/blog/post/fff-377)

The release date is undetermined at this time.

Here's a picture from the announcement:

[image]